# compute examples

Tags: r, vector, compare

(e.g)

V1<-c(1,2,3,4)
V2<-c(1,2,3,4)
FUNCTIONS
V3
[1]4 0

V1<-c(1,1,1,1)
V2<-c(1,2,3,4)
FUNCITONS
V3
[1]1 0

V1<-c(2,2,3,3)
V2<-c(1,2,3,4)
FUNCTIONS
V3
[1]2 0

V1<-c(1,1,3,4)
V2<-c(1,2,3,3)
FUNCTIONS
V3
[1]2 0

V1<-c(4,3,2,1)
V2<-c(1,2,3,4)
FUNCTIONS
V3
[1]0 4

V1<-c(4,3,4,3)
V2<-c(1,2,3,4)
FUNCTIONS
V3
[1]0 2

please have look at these new added examples, the function also need to satisfy this  two conditions

**V1<-c(1,1,2,2)
V2<-c(3,3,1,1)
FUNCTIONS
V3
[1]0 2**

**V1<-c(1,1,2,2)
V2<-c(3,3,3,1)
FUNCTIONS
V3
[1]0 1**

Comment: Are you sure that this: V1<-c(2,2,3,3) V2<-c(1,2,3,4) FUNCTIONS V3 [1]1 1, is correct? Given what you wrote i would expect the result to be [1] 2 0

Comment: your r right,that was typo, very sorry about that,wat I expect is [1]2 0 in that

Comment: Please have a look at the last 2 examples I added today, that two example explain the last condition I wanted to meet as the function given in answers actully gives the same outcome for the last 2 examples

Answer (score 2):

You might be after something like this.

```
> func <- function(x, y) { 
>   c(sum(x == y), 
>     length(y[match(unique(x), y, nomatch = 0)]) 
>     - sum(x == y))}

> V1<-c(4,3,2,1) 
> V2<-c(1,2,3,4)

> func(V1,V2)
[1] 0 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off of wkmor1's answer, you can simplify the y part of it using a set intersection.

```
func <- function(x, y) c(sum(x == y), length(intersect(x,y)))
```

This way it's a one-liner.

Comment: In the second part, you need to subtract the ones that are counted in the first part.

Comment: I suppose that is right from the examples, but the way it is worded in the question, the first part should not be subtracted.

Comment: I agree, the question is ambiguous and could do with being made clearer